# Swapping between Columns in excel sheet using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am new in java. Actually I want to swap two columns in excel sheet using java. I used the code but I didn't get correct output. I add screenshot of my excel sheet. I want to swap system name and date columns.

[image]

I also add screenshot of my incorrect output. I got 24 and 29 jan 1900 instead of 1-30th sept 2016.

[image]

```
CellStyle cellStyle1 = workbook11.createCellStyle();
CreationHelper createHelper1 = workbook11.getCreationHelper();
cellStyle1.setDataFormat(createHelper1.createDataFormat().getFormat("d-mmm"));
try {
    if (file11.exists()) {
        String dt = sh1.getRow(0).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
        if (!dt.equalsIgnoreCase("Date")) {
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator1 = sh1.iterator();
            while (rowIterator1.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator1.next();
                if (row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Date")) {
                    Cell cl1 = row.getCell(0);
                    Cell cl2 = row.getCell(1);
                    Cell temp = row.getCell(0);
                    Cell temp1 = row.getCell(1);
                    cl1.setCellValue(temp1.getStringCellValue());
                    cl2.setCellValue(temp.getStringCellValue());
                } else {
                    Cell cl1 = row.getCell(0);
                    Cell cl2 = row.getCell(1);
                    cl2.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    cl1.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    Cell temp = row.getCell(0);
                    Cell temp1 = row.getCell(1);
                    cl1.setCellValue(temp1.getStringCellValue());
                    cl2.setCellValue(temp.getStringCellValue());
                    row.getCell(1).setCellStyle(cellStyle1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
According to xenteros' answer I've tried the following:

```
         CellStyle cellStyle1 = workbook11.createCellStyle();
         CreationHelper createHelper1 = workbook11.getCreationHelper();
         cellStyle1.setDataFormat(createHelper1.createDataFormat().getFormat("d-mmm"));
          try {
                if (file11.exists()) {

                  String dt = sh1.getRow(0).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
                  if (!dt.equalsIgnoreCase("Date")) {
                  Iterator<Row> rowIterator1 = sh1.iterator();
                  while (rowIterator1.hasNext()) {
                  Row row = rowIterator1.next();
                 if (row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Date")) {
                 Cell cl1 = row.getCell(0);
                 Cell cl2 = row.getCell(1);
                 String temp = new String(cl2.getStringCellValue());
                 cl2.setCellValue(cl1.getStringCellValue());
                 cl1.setCellValue(temp);
          else {

                   Cell cl1 = row.getCell(0);
                   Cell cl2 = row.getCell(1);
                   cl2.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                   cl1.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                   String temp = new String(cl2.getStringCellValue());
                   System.out.println(temp);
                   java.util.Date temp2 = cl1.getDateCellValue();
                   cl2.setCellStyle(cellStyle1);
                   cl2.setCellValue(temp2);
                   cl1.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                   cl1.setCellValue(temp);
           }
}
```

Comment: Oh, C'mon! I've formatted your code so beutifuly! Why did you destroy it? What are those empty lines for?!

Comment: I have added long explanation to your code. Can You understand it? Did it help you or do you need further explanation?

Comment: Please indent your code properly. As it is now, the structure is hard to guess.

Comment: @RolandIllig as you might see it the edit history, I've already reformated this code twice. Hopefully The OP will leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer of this question.

try{

```
 if (file11.exists()) {
 String dt = sh1.getRow(0).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
 if (!dt.equalsIgnoreCase("Date")) {
 Iterator<Row> rowIterator1 = sh1.iterator();
 while (rowIterator1.hasNext()) {
 Row row = rowIterator1.next();                    
 DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();//instantiate DataFormatter class for reading the cell without changing the cell type
 Cell cl0 = row.getCell(0);
 Cell cl1 = row.getCell(1);
 CellStyle cs1 = cl0.getCellStyle();
 CellStyle cs2 = cl1.getCellStyle();
 String s1 = new String(df.formatCellValue(cl0));//store cell value as string
 String s2 = new String(df.formatCellValue(cl1));//store cell value as string
 cl1.setCellValue(s1);//perform swapping
 cl0.setCellStyle(cs2);
 cl1.setCellStyle(cs1);//perform swapping on formatting
 cl0.setCellValue(s2);//perform swapping  
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("File does not exist..................");
    }
 }
catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Report_File2);
    workbook11.write(out);
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You problem is basically about java references or about `swap` algorithm.

```
Memory:
+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------+
|   cell 1    |       cell 2       | cell 3 | cell 4 |
+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------+
| ["Date"...] | ["System name"...] |        |        |
+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------+

References before step 5:
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|  cl1   |  cl2  | temp  | temp1 |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| cell 1 | cell2 | cell1 | cell2 |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+

Memory after step 5:
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+--------+
|       cell 1       |       cell 2       | cell 3 | cell 4 |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+--------+
| ["System name"...] | ["System name"...] |        |        |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+--------+
References after step 5:
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|  cl1   |  cl2  | temp  | temp1 |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| cell 1 | cell2 | cell1 | cell2 |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+


1. Cell cl1 = row.getCell(0);
2. Cell cl2 = row.getCell(1);
3. Cell temp = row.getCell(0);
4. Cell temp1 = row.getCell(1);
5. cl1.setCellValue(temp1.getStringCellValue());
6. cl2.setCellValue(temp.getStringCellValue());
```

So... step 6 results in setting `cl2` cellValue to `temp`'s (which data is in cell1) value which is at the moment "System name".

The below will work but is unnecessary.

```
1. Cell cl1 = row.getCell(0);
2. Cell cl2 = row.getCell(1);
3. String temp1 = new String(cl1.getStringCellValue());
4. String temp2 = new String(cl2.getStringCellValue());
5. cl1.setCellValue(temp2);
6. cl2.setCellValue(temp1);
```

What you're trying to do is to swap the content of the cells. There is no need to swap cells on themselves. See what you can do:

```
1. Cell cl0 = row.getCell(0);
2. Cell cl1 = row.getCell(1);
3. String temp = new String(cl1.getStringValue());
4. cl1.setStringValue(cl0.getStringValue());
5. cl0.setStringValue(temp);


1. Cell cl0 = row.getCell(0);
2. Cell cl1 = row.getCell(1);
3. String temp = new String(cl1.getStringValue());
4. java.util.Date temp2 = cl0.getDateValue();
5. cl1.setCellStyle(cellStyle1);
6. cl1.setCellValue(temp2);
7. cl0.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
8. cl0.setCellValue(temp);
```

**Edit:**

As the OP is very tough, I paste the whole code here.

```
try {
    if (file11.exists()) {
        String dt = sh1.getRow(0).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
        if (!dt.equalsIgnoreCase("Date")) {
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator1 = sh1.iterator();
            while (rowIterator1.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator1.next();
                if (row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Date")) {
                    Cell cl0 = row.getCell(0);
                    Cell cl1 = row.getCell(1);
                    String temp = new String(cl1.getStringValue());
                    cl1.setStringValue(cl0.getStringValue());
                    cl0.setStringValue(temp);
                } else {
                    Cell cl0 = row.getCell(0);
                    Cell cl1 = row.getCell(1);
                    String temp = new String(cl1.getStringValue());
                    java.util.Date temp2 = cl0.getDateValue();
                    cl1.setCellStyle(cellStyle1);
                    cl1.setCellValue(temp2);
                    cl0.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    cl0.setCellValue(temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this code is only swap system name and date row not column. this is not swap all values. May be because of string because temp1 and temp2 are strings.

Comment: Yes. It's only for the if statement. OK, I'll give you the whole code.

Comment: @abcd I have just added working code for else statement. If it helps, please mark it as a solution and give an upvote.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts to my problem but my code is not going to else statement . this is doing only first row swap and terminate. I don't know why?

Comment: Please add your current code to the question. You can [edit] it. The code should be added at the very end with a remark that it is code refering to my answer.

Comment: @abcd you misschosen the if. I mean this if-else with condition `row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Date")`.

Comment: @abcd I added the whole code for you. I'm very disgusted at the moment. You should at least upvote this answer as it's your fault that you can't copy paste my code to yours. If I were your teacher, I would punish your for plagiarism, as I don't believe you know what the code you gave us do.